# AhkV1:Plaqued by 'Expression too long' error

Tags: autohotkey

I am working on two functions, `GetToolbar()` and `SetToolbar()` to control Adobe Illustrator's toolbar panel in a much more efficient way and to implement features such as spring loaded tools, which [illustrator still does not have](https://illustrator.uservoice.com/forums/333657-illustrator-desktop-feature-requests/suggestions/43625679-spring-loaded-tools).

I figured out everything I am just stuck on this error I that AutoHotkey is throwing at me:

```
: ==> Expression too long
AutoHotkey closed for the following exit code: 2
```

The way both functions work, is that they  associate a `x` and `y` (coordinates) value with each tool on [the toolbar](https://external-content.duckduckgo.com/iu/?u=http%3A%2F%2F3.bp.blogspot.com%2F-4TuL09IqQ-Y%2FUAVFHrRyr2I%2FAAAAAAAAAOg%2Fk8hXA3B2JPI%2Fs1600%2FToolbar.jpg&f=1&nofb=1&ipt=6ed076cc5bb0393f7109c62b2d9c89595130fa0af8ca8435f80e3d7c34cffb57&ipo=images). Illustrator has about 90 tools, and I would like to declare all of them:

```
setToolbar("Lasso")
setToolbar(toolName){
    toolIndex:= {"Selection"                :   {x:17, y:47}
                    ,"directSelection"      :   {x:47, y:47}
                    ,"groupSelection"           :   {x:17, y:47}
                    ,"MagicWand"                :   {x:47, y:71}
                    ,"Lasso"                        :   {x:17, y:95}
                    ,"Artboard"                 :   {x:47, y:95}
                    ,"FreeTransform"            :   {x:17, y:119}
                    ,"Pen"                      :   {x:47, y:119}
                    ,"AddAnchorPoint"           :   {x:17, y:143}
                    ,"DeleteAnchorPoint"        :   {x:47, y:143}
                    ,"AnchorPoint"              :   {x:17, y:167}
                    ,"Curvature"                :   {x:47, y:167}
                    ,"LineSegment"              :   {x:17, y:191}
                    ,"Arc"                      :   {x:47, y:191}
                    ,"RectangularGrid"      :   {x:17, y:215}
                    ,"PolarGrid"                :   {x:47, y:215}
                    ,"Spiral"                   :   {x:17, y:239}
                    ,"Flare"                        :   {x:47, y:239}
                    ,"Rectangle"                :   {x:17, y:263}
                    ,"RoundedRectangle"     :   {x:47, y:263}
                    ,"Ellipse"                  :   {x:17, y:287}
                    ,"Star"                     :   {x:47, y:287}
                    ,"Polygon"                  :   {x:17, y:311}
                    ,"Type"                     :   {x:47, y:311}
                    ,"VerticalType"         :   {x:17, y:335}
                    ,"VerticalAreaType"     :   {x:47, y:335}
                    ,"TypeOnPath"               :   {x:17, y:359}
                    ,"TouchType"                :   {x:47, y:359}
                    ,"VerticalTypeOnPath"   :   {x:17, y:383}
                    ,"AreaType"                 :   {x:47, y:383}
                    ,"Pencil"                   :   {x:17, y:407}
                    ,"Paintbrush"               :   {x:47, y:407}
                    ,"PathEraser"               :   {x:17, y:431}
                    ,"BlobBrush"                :   {x:47, y:431}
                    ,"Smooth"                   :   {x:17, y:455}
                    ,"Shaper"                   :   {x:47, y:455}
                    ,"Join"                     :   {x:17, y:479}
                    ,"SymbolSprayer"            :   {x:47, y:479}
                    ,"SymbolShifter"            :   {x:17, y:503}
                    ,"SymbolScruncher"      :   {x:47, y:503}
                    ,"SymbolSizer"              :   {x:17, y:527}
                    ,"SymbolSpinner"            :   {x:47, y:527}
                    ,"SymbolStainer"            :   {x:17, y:527}
                    ,"SymbolScreener"           :   {x:47, y:527}
                    ,"SymbolStyler"         :   {x:17, y:575}
                    ,"ColumnGraph"              :   {x:47, y:575}
                    ,"StackedColumnGraph"   :   {x:17, y:599}
                    ,"BarGraph"                 :   {x:47, y:599}
                    ,"StackedBarGraph"      :   {x:17, y:623}
                    ,"LineGraph"                :   {x:47, y:623}
                    ,"AreaGraph"                :   {x:17, y:647}
                    ,"ScatterGraph"         :   {x:47, y:647}
                    ,"PieGraph"                 :   {x:17, y:671}
                    ,"RadarGraph"               :   {x:47, y:671}
                    ,"Slice"                        :   {x:17, y:695}
                    ,"SliceSelection"           :   {x:47, y:695}
                    ,"Rotate"                   :   {x:17, y:719}
                    ,"PerspectiveGrid"      :   {x:47, y:719}
                    ,"PerspectiveSelection" :   {x:17, y:743}
                    ,"LivePaintSelection"   :   {x:47, y:743}
                    ,"Width"                        :   {x:17, y:767}
                    ,"Mesh"                     :   {x:47, y:767}
                    ,"Gradient"                 :   {x:17, y:791}
                    ,"Crystallize"              :   {x:47, y:791}
                    ,"ShapeBuilder"         :   {x:17, y:815}
                    ,"LivePaintBucke"           :   {x:47, y:815}
                    ,"PuppetWarp"               :   {x:17, y:839}
                    ,"Warp"                     :   {x:17, y:839}
                    ,"Reshape"                  :   {x:17, y:863}
                    ,"Twirl"                        :   {x:17, y:863}
                    ,"Reflect"                  :   {x:17, y:887}
                    ,"Scale"                        :   {x:17, y:887}
                    ,"Pucker"                   :   {x:17, y:911}
                    ,"Shear"                        :   {x:17, y:911}
                    ,"Bloat"                        :   {x:17, y:935}
                    ,"Scallop"                  :   {x:17, y:935}
                    ,"Eraser"                   :   {x:17, y:959}
                    ,"Eyedropper"               :   {x:17, y:959}
                    ,"Blend"                        :   {x:17, y:983}
                    ,"Scissors"                 :   {x:17, y:983}
                    ,"Knife"                        :   {x:17, y:191}
                    ,"Measure"                  :   {x:17, y:191}
                    ,"Wrinkle"                  :   {x:17, y:1031}
                    ,"RotateView"               :   {x:17, y:1031}
                    ,"PrintTiling"              :   {x:17, y:935}
                    ,"Hand"                     :   {x:17, y:935}
                    ,"Zoom"                     :   {x:17, y:1079}}

    print(toolIndex[toolName].x, toolIndex[toolName].y)   ; --> 17, 95
}
```

Attempting to run the above fails with Error:

```
: ==> Expression too long
AutoHotkey closed for the following exit code: 2
```

I can run it if I shorten it to something like this:

```
setToolbar("Lasso")
setToolbar(toolName){

    toolIndex:= {"Selection"                :   {x:17, y:47}
                    ,"directSelection"      :   {x:47, y:47}
                    ,"groupSelection"           :   {x:17, y:47}
                    ,"MagicWand"                :   {x:47, y:71}
                    ,"Lasso"                        :   {x:17, y:95}
                    ,"Artboard"                 :   {x:47, y:95}}

    print(toolIndex[toolName].x, toolIndex[toolName].y)
    }
```

It gets even worse in the case of `getToolbar()`, as I need to check what the active tools is and return a tool name, `x`, and `y` value back to the caller. But the expression runs over 50 lines long:

```
getToolbar(){
    hwnd    := winExist("Toolbar ahk_class OWL.Dock ahk_exe Illustrator.exe")
    pixel_getColor("ahk_id" hwnd, "BDBDBD",x, y)

    activeTool  := (x = 17 && y = 47)   ? {tool : "Selection",                  x:17, y:47}
                    :   (x = 47 && y = 47)  ? {tool : "directSelection",            x:47, y:47}
                    :   (x = 17 && y =  71) ? {tool : "groupSelection",         x:17, y:47}
                    :   (x = 47 && y =  71) ? {tool : "MagicWand",                  x:47, y:71}
                    :   (x = 17 && y =  95) ? {tool : "Lasso",                      x:17, y:95}
                    ....
                    ....
                    :   (x = 17 && y =  1031)   ? {tool : "RotateView",                 x:17, y:1031}
                    :   (x = 17 && y =  935)    ? {tool : "PrintTiling",                x:17, y:935}
                    :   (x = 17 && y =  935)    ? {tool : "Hand",                       x:17, y:935}
                    :   (x = 17 && y =  1079)   ? {tool: "Zoom",                            x:17, y:1079}
                    :""
    return activeTool
}
```

I solved it breaking the expression into parts using an `if` block but this is not desirable at all:

```
getToolbar(){
    hwnd    := winExist("Toolbar ahk_class OWL.Dock ahk_exe Illustrator.exe")
    pixel_getColor("ahk_id" hwnd, "BDBDBD",x, y)

    activeTool  := (x = 17 && y = 47)   ? {tool : "Selection",                  x:17, y:47}
                            :   (x = 47 && y = 47)  ? {tool : "directSelection",            x:47, y:47}
                            :   (x = 17 && y =  71) ? {tool : "groupSelection",         x:17, y:47}
                            ...
                            :   (x = 17 && y =  239)    ? {tool : "Spiral",                         x:17, y:239}
                            :   (x = 47 && y =  239)    ? {tool : "Flare",                      x:47, y:239}
        if (!activeTool){
            activeTool  := (x = 17 && y =   263)    ? {tool : "Rectangle",                  x:17, y:263}
                            :   (x = 47 && y =  263)    ? {tool : "RoundedRectangle",       x:47, y:263}
                            ...
                            :   (x = 17 && y =  455)    ? {tool : "Smooth",                         x:17, y:455}
                            :   (x = 47 && y =  455)    ? {tool : "Shaper",                         x:47, y:455}
        }if (!activeTool){
            activeTool  :=  (x = 17 && y =  479)    ? {tool : "Join",                       x:17, y:479}
                            :   (x = 47 && y =  479)    ? {tool : "SymbolSprayer",          x:47, y:479}
                            ...
                            :   (x = 17 && y =  671)    ? {tool : "PieGraph",                   x:17, y:671}
                            :   (x = 47 && y =  671)    ? {tool : "RadarGraph",                 x:47, y:671}
        }if (!activeTool){
            activeTool  :=  (x = 17 && y =  695)    ? {tool : "Slice",                      x:17, y:695}
                            :   (x = 47 && y =  695)    ? {tool : "SliceSelection",             x:47, y:695}
                            ...
                            :   (x = 17 && y =  887)    ? {tool : "Reflect",                    x:17, y:887}
                            :   (x = 17 && y =  887)    ? {tool : "Scale",                      x:17, y:887}
        }if (!activeTool){
            activeTool  :=  (x = 17 && y =  911)    ? {tool : "Pucker",                         x:17, y:911}
                            :   (x = 17 && y =  911)    ? {tool : "Shear",                      x:17, y:911}
                            ....
                            :   (x = 17 && y =  1031)   ? {tool : "RotateView",                 x:17, y:1031}
                            :   (x = 17 && y =  1079)   ? {tool: "Zoom",                            x:17, y:1079}
                            :""
                            }
    return activeTool
    }
```

I searched quite a bit and have not turned up with anything. Is there a  way forward here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Seems to me that the obvious solution here is that you shouldn't have such a thing defined in code in the first place. This belongs to some config file from which you could read it into the program.